# is hector_slam includes any kind of kalman filter? if not, how should i do?

Tags: slam, navigation, ekf, sicklms, kalman

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have -only- LMS100 lidar and can create map with hector_slam. My question is hector_slam includes filters like kalman filter or extended kalman filter (EKF)?

If hector_slam itself doesnt include it, how should i do the filter when creating map with hector_slam??

Thanks, Basak

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235596/is-hector_slam-includes-any-kind-of-kalman-filter?-if-not,-how-should-i-do?/) by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-05-30**:
What do you want to achieve with the KF? Do you want to localize in the map built using `hector_slam` ?

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-05-30**:
actually i dont need to localization(but hector_slam does it anyway-with no odometry data) my graduate thesis is just about mapping but my teacher said "use some filter like kalman to get better results and it should be more academic!" :/ so i'm looking for to do in hector_slam which i currently use

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-05-30**:
I can't help with that, but here's something you might find useful as you're working on your thesis: [http://home.isr.uc.pt/~davidbsp/publications/SPR_SSRR2013_SLAM.pdf](http://home.isr.uc.pt/%7Edavidbsp/publications/SPR_SSRR2013_SLAM.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no Kalman Filter included in the hector_mapping executable, but the output can be fed to a filtering framework. I think [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) is the most used and best documented one. There is also [hector_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_localization), but there is no extensive documentation available.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-05-31**:
thanks for the answer, i'm gonna check them. Can i ask a little bit unrelated question? (to the one of the creater of hector_slam :)) is the represantation of map from hector_slam is occuancy grid or something else?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-05-31**:
Yes, it's using a (2D) occupancy gridmap representation.

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-06-01**:
by the way, does it include or use any kind of filter in hector_slam itself when extracting and building map from laser data, (not in the localization part)?